# Null Killing vectors constrain the space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, vector-fields, geodesics

I have heard that spacetimes which admit null Killing vectors are sort of constrained. I wish to know how and why? What makes null Killing vectors so special?

Comment: Can you give more context? The set of spacetimes with *any* Killing vectors is constrained, because most spacetimes don't have them. (Killing vectors are associated with isometries. See [Must every isometry have an associated Killing vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98119))

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly For example.in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6216, the author states in section 2.2 that null killing vectors significantly constrain the space-time.

Comment: Killing vectors encode symmetry. For perspective, consider "all metal objects" to be analogous to unconstrained spacetime, whereas "all metal cylinders" to be analogous to constrained spacetime, since those objects have a particular symmetry (cylindrical).