# "Killing leaves" in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, terminology, vector-fields

I now about [Killing vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) in GR but recently stumbled upon the notion of "Killing leaves" and couldn't find any simple explanation of this notion. For example, [this paper](http://cds.cern.ch/record/599491/files/0301020.pdf) writes: "integral submanifolds generated by vector fields of a Killing algebra are called Killing leaves." What exactly are Killing leaves and why are they important?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 3, it's defined as:

> *integral submanifolds* of the distribution, generated by vector fields of a Killing  algebra $\mathcal{G}$, are called *Killing leaves*,

A good overview of a (tangent) distribution and how it relates to the foliation of a manifold into "leaves" (hypersurfaces) might be found [here](https://msu.edu/~ottensam/Foliations.pdf), or on [notes about the Frobenius theorem](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/16F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec11.pdf), or [John Armstrong's blogpost](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/integral-submanifolds/).