# What is the meaning of Killing vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields

What is the meaning of [Killing vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field)? I know that  if $ \textbf{X}\in\mathfrak{X}(\mathcal{M})$, let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a pair who define my riemannian manifold, The killing vector fiels is defined by $\mathcal{L}_{\textbf{X}}g=0$. So i think that $g$ is invariant under the flow of the integral curves generated by $\textbf{X}$. However i do not know the physical meaning of this applying to a $g$.

I want to know the meaning cause i want to arrive to stationary hamilton-jacobi equation using the properties of killing vector field but i do not if i could apply to classical mechanics.

Steps!

$[X,Y]f=XYf-YXf=Xg(X,Y)-Yg(X,X)=g(\nabla_{X}X,Y)+g(X,\nabla_{X}Y)-2g(X,\nabla_{Y}X)=g(X,[X,Y])$

On the other hand:

$g(X,[X,Y])=g(X,\nabla_{X}Y)-g(X,\nabla_{Y}X)$

$g(X,\nabla_{X}Y)-g(X,\nabla_{Y}X)=g(\nabla_{X}X,Y)+g(X,\nabla_{X}Y)-2g(X,\nabla_{Y}X)\Rightarrow$

$\Rightarrow g(\nabla_{X}X,Y)=g(X,\nabla_{Y}X)$ So here is when i use the killing vector field propertie of $g(X,\nabla_{Y}X)=-g(\nabla_{X}X,Y)$ to get $g(\nabla_{X}X,Y)=0$

Answer (score 3):

A Killing vector $K^\mu(x) $  is an infinitessimal *isometry*. In other words: take the manifold and  move all the points from coordinates $x^\mu$ to $x^\mu+\epsilon K^\mu(x) $. If $K$ was Killing then the geodesic distance between any two the points is the same as it was before. For example on a 2-sphere with polar coordinates $\theta,\phi$ a movement that leaves $\theta$ fixed but take $\phi$ to $\phi+\epsilon$ is a Killing vector becuase it is just an infinitesimal rotation about the $z$ axis, and rotations dont change distances.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, so If i have a system such the energy is conserve, could i say that the hamiltonian vector field $\textbf{X}_{h}=\dot q\frac{\partial}{\partial q}+\dot p\frac{\partial}{\partial p}$ is Killing vector field? I think the geodesic will be the same when the time start in t and t0?

Comment: You Hamiltonian example with $\dot p, \dot q$ s surely for a symplectic manifold rather than a Riemann one...

Comment: So if i have a simplectic manifold, Does the hamiltonian vector field always be Killing vector field?

Comment: I've never heard of Killing vector fields in symplectic geometry.  Any Hamiltonian flow is an infinitesimal symplectomorphism, so such flows  are two-a-penny. Killing vector fields require symmetries that not all  Riemann manifolds possess. Of course some symplectic manifolds also have a preferred metric. Is that  your case?

Comment: I ask this case i want to solve the exercise 6.32 of https://students.iiserkol.ac.in/~mms15ms051/courses/PH4105/Differentiable-Manifolds-A-Theoretical-Physics-Approach.pdf (p 139). I arrive to $g(\nabla _{\textbf{X}}\textbf{X},\textbf{Y})=g(\textbf{X},\nabla_{\textbf{Y}}\textbf{X})$ and the only way that i know to arrive $\nabla_{\textbf{X}}\textbf{X}=0$ is using killing vector field properties. This result is so useful to get stationary hamilton-jacobi equation $H(q,\frac{\partial W}{\partial q})=E$.

Comment: So if the only way to solve that exercise is supposing $\textbf{X}$ is killing vector field, this means that the metric along the integral curves of $\textbf{X}$ is constant, but i do not know how to prove this statement, sorry for replying late

Comment: I did excercise 6.32 without using any Killing field notions. You just follow the hints remembering that  that that $X={\rm grad} f$ implies $g(X,Y)=Yf$, $g(X,[X,Y])= [X,Y]f$ and so on. Then you see that $Yg(X,X)=0$ for all $Y$ implies that  $g(\nabla_X X,Y)=0$ for all $Y$  which in turn  implies that $\nabla_XX=0$.

Comment: I do not know how you get $g(\nabla_{X}X,Y)=0$ from $Yg(X,X)=0$, beacuse if you checj the equation 6.53 of the book i share you you get $Yg(X,X)=2g(\nabla_{Y}X,X)$ i have edited the main and you can see what i am doing

Comment: I'll add an answer with the derivation.

Comment: Actually I see that you have almost all of it.   You are just missing the fact that $g(X,\nabla_YX)= (1/2)Yg(X,X)=0$ becasue $g(_,_)$ is symmetric..

Comment: So, $Yg(X,X)=0$ beacuse $g(X,X)=constant?$

Comment: Yes. For all vector fields $Y$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! God bless you